# Trying to find a modern murder / suspense with reverse chronology

Tags: identification-request

I read a book a few years ago that I can't remember the name of. From what I can remember of the plot, a man and a woman committed murder and then covered it up. It begins at the end (reverse chronology) and works its way back to the beginning. I think the woman is visiting a town she grew up in, or vice versa. The 2 characters had rekindled a relationship. The "end" (beginning) scene involved overalls, them setting fire to a field together, coffee in her old house that she's fixing up? Deputy interrogations. I can't remember who they killed and why, but there seemed to be a good reason from what I remember. Honestly I can't remember much more than that!

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please read the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] your question with further details. For example, do you remember what age this book was aimed at? Was it paperback or hardcover? What did the front cover look like? What language was the book in, and do you think it may have been a translation? Approximately where in the world was this book set? What does "Deputy interrogations." as a sentence by itself mean?

Comment: TV Tropes [lists several back-to-front](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BackToFront) stories, although none seems an obvious match. The [Wikipedia page Reverse Chronology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_chronology) also has some examples.